# OSX: Terminal Zip command not working

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I am trying to zip a folder from terminal command (given below)

```
zip myZip.zip path\ Of\ the\ Folder
```

The above command providing the given below result

[image]

is My Command wrong. Please help, I have to do it with terminal command only.

**Edit**

I also tried these command and none of them work. (Results are also given)

**NO.1**

```
n:~ myUser$ zip -r abc.zip /Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img\ for\ seg/
  adding: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/ (stored 0%)
  adding: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/aaaa copy 3.jpg (deflated 21%)
  adding: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/aaaa copy 6.jpg (deflated 21%)
  adding: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/aaaa copy 64.jpg (deflated 21%)
  adding: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/aaaa copy 7.jpg (deflated 21%)
  adding: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/aaaa copy.jpg (deflated 21%)
  adding: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/aaaa mo e.jpg (deflated 21%)
  adding: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/aaaa moved.jpg (deflated 21%)
  adding: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/aaaa.jpg (deflated 21%)
  adding: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/moved aaaa.jpg (deflated 21%)
  adding: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/Screen Shot 2015-12-11 at 1.jpg (deflated 21%)
  adding: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/Screen-Shot-2015-12-11-at-1.17.11-pm_03.png (deflated 19%)
  adding: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/Screen-Shot-2015-12-11-at-1.17.11-pm_05.png (deflated 21%)
  adding: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/Screen-Shot-2015-12-11-at-1.17.11-pm_10.png (deflated 26%)
n:~ myUser$
```

**No. 2**

```
n:~ myUser$ zip myZip.zip /Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img\ for\ seg
  adding: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/ (stored 0%)
n:~ myUser$
```

**No. 3**

```
n:~ myUser$ zip myZip.zip -r /Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img\ for\ seg
updating: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/Screen Shot 2015-12-11 at 1.jpg (deflated 21%)
updating: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/Screen-Shot-2015-12-11-at-1.17.11-pm_03.png (deflated 19%)
updating: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/Screen-Shot-2015-12-11-at-1.17.11-pm_05.png (deflated 21%)
updating: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/Screen-Shot-2015-12-11-at-1.17.11-pm_10.png (deflated 26%)
updating: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/aaaa copy 3.jpg (deflated 21%)
updating: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/aaaa copy 6.jpg (deflated 21%)
updating: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/aaaa copy 64.jpg (deflated 21%)
updating: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/aaaa copy 7.jpg (deflated 21%)
updating: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/aaaa copy.jpg (deflated 21%)
updating: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/aaaa mo e.jpg (deflated 21%)
updating: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/aaaa moved.jpg (deflated 21%)
updating: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/aaaa.jpg (deflated 21%)
updating: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/moved aaaa.jpg (deflated 21%)
updating: Users/myUser/Desktop/Assets/img for seg/ (stored 0%)
n:~ myUser$
```

**Edit 2:** The above commands are making a zip but the zip does not have any content that was present in the actual folder(source folder)
[image]

Comment: "My Command wrong" is not a symptom, it's just a complaint. What *specifically* is `zip` doing that you don't like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command

```
pushd /Users/myUser/Desktop && zip -r ./temp.zip ./Assets && popd
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to zip a folder and its contents, you need the `-r` (recursive) options.

For reference:

- [zip(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/zip.1.html) (OSX uses libarchive, which follows info-zip)
- [info-zip](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/zip.html)

Comment: @thomas_dickey your idea did't work. I have updated the question and given all command's result. Please have a look

Comment: You've lost the point in your question, seems that you are changing the question but have not yet *asked* a new question.

Comment: I apologise If I have lost my point but. I just want to zip a folder using `terminal`

Comment: The output in your revised question using the `-r` option looks correct, and in a quick check on OSX, it works.  Some clarification is needed to get further advice.